# Summation notation for matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 4x4 matrix in Matlab named P. I want to raise P to a power (say, X) to create a new 4x4 matrix. Then, I want to sum that matrix from 0 to 51 (i.e. P^0 + P^1 + ... + P^52)

Of course, this would take far too long to write all the way out. Is there a way to shorten this?

I have already tried the following code:

```
 syms k

 symsum(P^k, k, [0 51])
```

which does not return what I want.

Thanks

Comment: `0` to `51` doesn't include `52`

Comment: Please notice that `matrix power` [(^)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html) is different than element-wise power [(.^)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html).

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized solution can be done with [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) like so:

```
result = sum(bsxfun(@power, P, reshape(0:51, [1 1 52])), 3);
```

For MATLAB versions R2016b and later, this can be done with [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) (known as "broadcasting" in other languages):

```
result = sum(P.^reshape(0:51, [1 1 52]), 3);
```

If you really are trying to do it [symbolically](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/) and not getting the result you want, it may be because you are using the wrong operator. The [matrix power operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html) is `^`, while the [element-wise power operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) is `.^`. You may be wanting this (where `P` is a 4-by-4 numeric matrix):

```
syms k
symsum(P.^k, k, [0 51])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you were using symbolic math, I hope you'd be having no problem with a loop.

```
req_sum = zeros(size(P));
for k=0:51                   %loop for all the powers
    req_sum = req_sum + P^k; %adding the results of each iteration
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like the following using `subs` (in octave):

```
syms 'P' 'k';
subs(symsum(P^k, k, [0 51]), [1 1;1 1])
```

For example `P = [1 1; 1 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a place, after some good ideas from @gnovice, my intuition was simply to vectorize it. That just another manner to what gnovice did, but in my opinion it's more readable than `bsxfun`.

```
result=reshape(sum(P(:).^[0:51],2),size(P))
```